# Translate a div inside a webpage using Google translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-translate

As i said in the title is it possible to translate just a **div** in my webpage using google translator API.?

Answer (score 1):

use the javascript REST trick. See example [here](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#translate)

Note: now Google translate api since v2 is a **paid service** and has limitation in terms of it's uses.